# Not able to retrieve all the cookies

Tags: java, android, cookies, cookiestore

I am able to retrieve only 1 out of the 3 set cookies, could you point out what could be the error? The code and corresponding log is :

```
BasicClientCookie cookieprotected = null;
                     for (int i=0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                        Header h = headers[i];

                        if(h.getName().equals("Set-Cookie"))
                        {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Header names: "+h.getName());
                        Log.i(TAG, "Header Value: "+h.getValue());

                        cookieprotected = new BasicClientCookie("Set-Cookie",h.getValue());
                        cookieStore.addCookie(cookieprotected);
                        System.out.println("cookie protected " + cookieprotected.getValue().toString());
                        }
                     }

                     System.out.println("cookie protected 2 " + cookieprotected.getValue().toString());

                     List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
                     Log.i("CustomHttpClient","Cookies size= " + cookies.size());
                     for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                         Cookie cookie = cookies.get(i);
                         Log.i("CustomHttpClient","Local cookie: " + cookie);
                         Cookie mSessionCookie = cookie;
                         Log.i("CustomHttpClient",""+cookie.getValue());
                     }
```

log output:

```
09-17 14:57:57.763: I/Cookie(781): Header names: Set-Cookie
09-17 14:57:57.763: I/Cookie(781): Header Value: JSESSIONID=0000u0yVi-4M4su-sq2Tblj9buK:16uiuppr9; Path=/
09-17 14:57:57.773: I/Cookie(781): Header names: Set-Cookie
09-17 14:57:57.773: I/Cookie(781): Header Value: PD-H-SESSION-ID=4_1_zAHen1PYrVQ+ae7Woskqy0IEcSu09rpXmIVNIGptI6tvFyNn; Domain=.net; Path=/
09-17 14:57:57.773: I/Cookie(781): Header names: Set-Cookie
09-17 14:57:57.773: I/Cookie(781): Header Value: PD-ID=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; Domain=.stage.net; Path=/; Secure

    09-17 14:39:36.443: I/CustomHttpClient(715): Cookies size= 1
    09-17 14:39:36.453: I/CustomHttpClient(715): Local cookie: [version: 0][name: Set-Cookie][value: PD-ID=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; Domain=.stage..net; Path=/; Secure][domain: null][path: null][expiry: null]
    09-17 14:39:36.453: I/CustomHttpClient(715): PD-ID=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; Domain=.stage.net; Path=/; Secure
```

Comment: your cookie name is always Set-Cookie. You need to split your header value on '=' to get the cookie name and value

Comment: @njzk2 Did not exactly get what you meant, a line of code would be helpful. Thanks !

Comment: What doing`cookieStore.addCookie(cookieprotected);` method? Can you show this code?

Comment: @herry This method adds all the set-cookies (supposed to be 3 of them) to an object called cookieProtected

Comment: BasicClientCookie expect a cookie name and a value. For example, for the first one you give Set-Cookie name and JSESSIONID=0000u0yVi-4..., but you should give name = JSESSIONID and value 0000u0yVi-4... You need to split the value of the Set-Cookie header on the '=' character

Comment: @staytrue So, you declared one cookieStore in the beginning of this program. The cookieStore has one collection (List, Collection etc.) attribute. My question is your addCookie method add new element to existing collection attribute or first recreate new collection and second step add new element? How to declared this collection in your class?

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
String [] cookie = h.getValue().split("=");
cookieprotected = new BasicClientCookie(cookie[0], cookie[1]);
```

That's because you always use the same name ("Set-Cookie") for your cookie, resulting in successive cookies overwriting the previous ones

Comment: Thanks so much, I don't have enough reputation to upvote the answer.

Comment: If you think the answer is helpful to you. You don't have to upvote it, just check the answer. Then you will receive 2 reputations :)

Answer (score 0):

Tried following code, it will store the cookies retrieved automatically.

```
cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();       
HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();

if(cookieStore != null){
    httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
}
response = client.execute(httpPost,httpContext);
```

Comment: @edisonthk... the code i posted is after receiving the httppost response, could there be an issue with the logic of the cookie store itself ?

Comment: I am able to retrieve 2 out of the 3 cookies now, Thanks. Wonder what the problem is.

Comment: @edisonthk...yes, i tried that...it is not retrieving the last cookie